# Find and replace using Regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a field of the below format in my text file:

```
to_timestamp('03-NOV-15 09.08.23.449041000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')
```

There are hundreds of such values, each value would be unique, but of the below format.

```
to_timestamp('<unique date>','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')
```

I want to replace this format with *sysdate()*

I'm pretty much new to this regex. Can someone please help?

**EDIT:**

*Current text*:

```
Insert into table (column1,column2) values (12,to_timestamp('03-NOV-15 09.08.23.449041000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
Insert into table (column1,column2) values (23,to_timestamp('05-DEC-15 12.02.22.301161000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
Insert into table (column1,column2) values (34,to_timestamp('05-DEC-15 12.02.22.380390000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
```

*Required text*:

```
Insert into table (column1,column2) values (12,sysdate());
Insert into table (column1,column2) values (23,sysdate());
Insert into table (column1,column2) values (34,sysdate());
```

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/q/1510738/763386) and give more context and expected result.

Comment: Please find the update @Toto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bto_timestamp\(.+?\)`
- Replace with: `sysdate\(\)`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b                  # word boundary
to_timestamp        # literally
\(                  # opening parenthesis
    .+?             # 1 or more any character, not greedy
\)                  # closing parenthesis
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]